# What's meaning of this method checkDuplicate ? Whats happening inside this code?

Tags: java, android

```
public static boolean checkDuplicate(ArrayList<String> list) {

        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            boolean isUnique = set.add(list.get(i));
            if (!isUnique) {
                return isUnique;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: It checks if there are any repeated elements in a list. If there are any duplicates, it returns `false`. If there are no duplicates, it returns `true`. `set.add(x)` returns `true` if `x` was not already in the set.

Comment: Can you please say what will happen in every line of the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set.add` will return `false` if the element that you wish to add to the Set already exists in the Set (and therefore wasn't added). Your method returns `false` if `set.add` returns false for at least one of the elements of the input List, which means is does what its name implies - checks for duplicates.

```
public static boolean checkDuplicate(ArrayList<String> list) {

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { // iterate over all elements of input list
        boolean isUnique = set.add(list.get(i)); // returns false if list.get(i) 
                                                 // is already in the Set
        if (!isUnique) { // returns false if a non unique element was found
            return isUnique;
        }
    }
    return true; // return true if all the elements in the input List are unique

}
```

Comment: Thank you . understood well . I'm new to this site. I'm having more question how can i ask

Comment: @Senthu You're welcome! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have another question, just post another question.

Comment: Can't able to post a question. It says that I can post after 90 mins

Comment: Can I  have your email id if possible . For a presentation I need some explanations for some codes . Presentation is on tomorrow .

Comment: @Senthu No, sorry. Just wait until you can ask another question.

Comment: I have posted another question can u see it

Answer (score 0):

In 'Set' interface add method have Boolean return type. And Set contain only unique value. If you try to insert duplicate value its return false.

Comment: Can you please say what will happen in every line of the code ?

Comment: Which line of code confused you?

Comment: Why it uses HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); this code ? and also  boolean isUnique = set.add(list.get(i));
            if (!isUnique) {
                return isUnique;
            }